# WriteProcessMemory with an int value

Tags: c#, winapi

How do I `WriteProcessMemory` with an `int` value?

Comment: Why are you calling writeprocessmemory in C#, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Hans Passant I am rolling on the floor :))

Comment: I'm making cheats to a game, and I need to set Server and Port, and server = string, and Port = INT

Comment: I have an example of both reading and writing like this for botting in games on my blog. http://www.jarloo.com/reading-and-writing-to-memory/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your note I assume you are trying to set a int (The port?) in the game to some value. You will need to know the game's handle and the address of the value you want to change.

```
public class Cheat
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll",SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte [] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    public static void SetPort(IntPtr GameHandle, IntPtr WriteAddress, int i)
    {
        var array = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
        int bytesWritten;
        WriteProcessMemory(GameHandle, WriteAddress, array, (uint)array.Length, out bytesWritten);
    }
{
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to expand your question.  Are you looking for the P/Invoke signature for that method?  If so:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.writeprocessmemory